# echo unicode not actually scaping the characters

Tags: bash, unicode, fonts, terminal, echo

I'm trying to run the following command, in theory It should output a Unicode character with a clock (because I'm using a NerdFont). I know for a fact that the font works, because of some `neovim` plugins, so I think that It's not font support.

The command, should output the font character

```
$ echo -e '\uef3c'
\uEF3C
$ echo -e "\u03ea"
\u03EA
$ printf "\u03ea\n"
\u03EA
```

Any Idea where else can I look and check what could be wrong?

Comment: I assume you want `echo` to *unescape* the character, not to [e]scape it, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `locale` and check that you are set to a value that supports your character.  Update the settings if necessary.  (You should be able to see that replacing your character with `\u41` prints an `A` which will indicate it is related to your locale.)

For example, when set to `en_US.UTF-8` you should get your desired character but if it is set to `C` (for example) you will see the `\uEF3C`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Maybe try `printf` instead of `echo`?

```
printf '\uef3c\n'
```

Comment: sorry, same story, I just added the example.

Comment: What version of bash do you use? What terminal?

Comment: ST terminal, and GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).